# What version of DirectX should I use to make a 2D desktop GUI application?

Tags: windows, user-interface, directx, desktop-application

I want to make a 2D desktop GUI application with DirectX but I don't know which version to use. I initially tried Direct2D but it never really gained popularity, thus there isn't a lot of community support or documentation for it compared to the rest of DirectX, so it's not an option.

So I have three options:

1. DirectX 9.0c
2. DirectX 10
3. DirectX 11 (not 11.1, I'm not getting Windows 8)

A knowledgeable friend of mine strongly encouraged DirectX 9.0c saying that's all I need, but I am wary of using an 8-year old platform. Microsoft is pretty much the zenith of legacy support but I think that they must have a limit. I have no idea of the difference between DX10 and DX11.

Keep in mind that I'm very much a novice programmer so this is mostly a learning project.

Any advice is appreciated!

Edit: I'd also appreciate advice on any significant differences in functionality or programming paradigms between the versions.

Comment: Any reason you're going with DirectX and not the regular Windows API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What version of DirectX should I use to make a 2D desktop GUI application?

DirectX 9, because you'll get more users.

> A knowledgeable friend of mine strongly encouraged DirectX 9.0c saying that's all I need, but I am wary of using an 8-year old platform.

Many DirectX 7 and DirectX 5 games still work just fine, not to mention titles that use DirectDraw. So there's no problem with 8-year old platform. Using newer (than 9) version might not even benefit you, so blindly going for higher version number isn't a good idea.

Depending on your circumstances you could also consider using OpenGL but that choice makes sense only if your app has to be cross-platform. If you know that application will be windows-only, then choosing DirectX 9 makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's primary commitment is to its Windows customers.  Who still run 15 years old games that use whatever DirectX version was in use back then.  IDirectDraw is alive and well.  Clearly you'll benefit from that as a developer secondarily.  And sure, DX 9 is most widely supported by hardware so that's an excellent choice.  Consider something higher if your game performs poorly on old hardware, the DX version is an automatic selector.

Comment: Thanks! By the way, I'm not programming a game, but rather a desktop application (relatively simple graphics, barely any math). Do you know if there are significant differences in functionality between DX versions? Any changes in programming concepts?

Comment: That's another question.  Click the "Ask Question" button to ask it.

Comment: They're related questions that help answer the original question. I don't want to create a new question for the same motive.

Comment: That's just not how SO works, it a Q+A site.  One Q, one A.  It is not a forum where you can just keep asking follow-up questions.  Consider using social.msdn.microsoft.com as a forum site that works the way you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Are you writing this for work, or for fun?

If it's for work, then you have to go by the minimum system requirements that someone in business or marketing has defined. If your minimum OS can be Win7 or Vista SP2 w/ Platform Update, then Direct2D is a viable option. Otherwise, DX9 is the way you have to go.

If it's for fun on your own personal time, then do whatever you think will be the most fun :) Direct2D will certainly be MUCH easier to work with if you just want to do 2D graphics. I wouldn't worry much about the "it hasn't gained popularity/community support" angle, especially because it's being used by all the major desktop apps nowadays (Firefox, Internet Explorer, and even the next version of Paint.NET). Also, Win8 will update Direct2D with a whole bunch of interesting new features (and this update will also be available for Win7 from what I understand).

Direct2D can be clumsy to work with at first, but that's mainly due to all the COM stuff. Once you get used to it and build up your own little utilities warchest, it's really not any more complicated than GDI+. In fact, I've been able to port a bunch of old GDI+ code to using Direct2D/DirectWrite and often it's just a line-by-line substitution, e.g. SolidBrush -> SolidColorBrush (this is in the Paint.NET 4.0 code base, btw).

Comment: "build up your own little utilities warchest" In this case it'll be more reasonable to use framework that comes with warchest.

Comment: Well in my case, it has to do with being able to create something like a SolidColorBrush without needing to first create the render target, and then have internal bits which create the "real" ID2D1SolidColorBrush as-needed. This is great since I don't have to worry about recreating resources and the plumbing for that at every single place I want to use D2D. So actually I guess you're right, since my "framework" is my own .NET interop layer for D2D, DWrite, etc. :)

Comment: This is for fun. By the way, I've tried Direct2D...I had heaps of trouble trying to render a bitmap on the screen; you have to mess around with the Windows Imaging Component, and even then it couldn't understand the data in the bitmap resource I was trying to render. In Direct3D, there's a function called `CreateTextureFromResource`. Works flawlessly. I decided that Direct2D wasn't worth the trouble when I could use the more popular and documented Direct3D. Thanks for your response!

Comment: Bitmaps really aren't that bad to work with in WIC+Direct2D, but it's one of those areas that is incredibly clumsy until you reach that "aha!" moment and everything clicks. I've been working with various Windows graphics/UI APIs over the years so I'm used to this kinda stuff. I think the biggest hurdle is realizing that what Direct2D calls a "bitmap" (ID2D1Bitmap) should really be thought of as a "device bitmap" -- it lives over on the graphics card and if you need to manipulate pixels then you gotta do that on the CPU side with a "regular bitmap" (IWICBitmap) first (or various other tricks).

Answer (score 1):

I used the Direct 2D to render graphs of functions and it's pretty easy to use - I'd say, as simple as GDI+. I'd guess, that level of complexity of DirectX 11 and DirectX 9 (in terms of 2D graphics) is quite similar, so don't worry about that.

DirectX 9.0 runs on (let's say) all modern computers, and 11 restricts you to Windows Vista (with platform pack) and Windows 7. Take into consideration, though, that Windows XP will eventually vanish and DirectX will evolve, so I'm not sure, is it worth investing your time into technology, which won't be developed anymore. I would suggest DirectX 11's Direct2D then.